# Importing with composer without using require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to understand how to import with composer without using require `__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

This is a Wordpress plugin I wrote:

```
<?php

use Google\Auth;

namespace google;

class GoogleClient
{


  function __construct($applicationName, $filePath) {
  }

  public function getClient($applicationName, $filepath)
  {

    $client = new Google_Client();

    return $client;
  }

}
```

I get an error on `Google_Client()`; I am trying to use the use syntax, but I am not sure what I need to put there in order to make it work.

This is my composer file:

```json
{
  "require": {
    "google/apiclient": "^2.10"
     }
}
```

This is another script I wrote, where I do use composer's autoloader:

```php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    
function getClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    return $client;
}
```

I can instantiate `Google_Client()` from the script, but I can't from the plugin I wrote. I am not sure what I need to import exactly from google/apiclient. I am thinking I need to use Google/ApiClient, but the option isn't there.

This is my `autoload_psr4.php` file in the PHP project:

```
<?php

// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);
return array(
    'Google\\Auth\\' => array($vendorDir . '/google/auth/src'),
    'Google\\' => array($vendorDir . '/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-
);
```

Not sure why use Google\Auth doesn't seem to work. I get symbol Auth is declared, but is not used and I still get an error on `Google_Client()`; Not sure if it's just Visual Studio Code not being able to determine there's no error, or whether it cannot import anything.

Comment: If you don't load the autoloader, how is it supposed to find your file?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the autoloader Composer provides? A self-written autoloader wouldn't look that much different

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to tell you this, but this is a fool's errand. It makes no sense.

If you don't import composer's autoloader, you'll need to read each of the package classes so they are found when you do  when you try to instantiate a class in the package.

But not only that. The package itself [depends on many other packages](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/3a981757c0e6f89931dbe6a895f4e0f7610f50b5/composer.json#L8), so it's liable to try to instantiate any of those classes at some point. You'd need to import (`require` or `include`) **those** files too. And those packages may have multiple classes, and/or depend on *other* packages, etc.

So in the end you'll end with either:

- a huge list of `require`s somewhere in your code (bad and ineficcient)
- a custom built autoloader (waste of effort, it'll take you a long time to get it right, and best case scenario, it's no better than composer's.

Do yourself a favour and just use `vendor/autoload.php`.